# Two monitors causing crash with same Nvidia graphics card

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors

Okay, well, I'm mildly surprised I don't see this question asked yet, as PP as I like to call it (12.04) boasted support for two monitors.

Why can I not use two monitors? My current set-up is kinda sketchy, so that's probably why. But what part of it is screwed up? Alright. I have an GeForce NVidia 9800 that has two output slots, and I have them hooked up to two computer screens of different resolution. I have it working perfectly in Windows. It also works well in the Ubuntu sign-in screen. However, the problem here lies whenever I sign into my user. I sign in like normal, but the second screen shuts off. When I go to "Displays", it recognizes the screen for me and lets me configure it just like in Windows. HOWEVER, whenever I click apply, it crashes my system and I must restart and it comes back without the new settings.

Yes, I'm using the correct resolutions and I'm not mirroring. I believe I'm also up-to-date on my drivers.

What is wrong here? Is this a known problem I'm unaware of?

Comment: you are using the "Monitor" option under the gear on the top right corner of your desktop?

Comment: Well, I used the Dash thing, but yeah, that's the same tool.

Comment: using the control panel that comes with your drivers is always a better idea, also you probably have to specify what kind of connections you use to connect your monitors.

Comment: .. I would if I knew what they were xD ;] Whatever it is, it's likely not the connection because it works on Windows.

Comment: HAHAHA, okay, you guys wanna hear something funny? I reinstalled my drivers, now it will only recognize my smaller screen and it designates it "laptop." What??

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out myself. I had to reinstall my drivers and use the "NVidia X Server Settings" and it took me a while to set up, but it works :D